# Reverse sort data in Google Sheet

Tags: forms, sorting, google-sheets

Google Forms linked to Google Sheets record submissions oldest to newest. We must scroll to the bottom of the sheet for the newest submission. I'd like to reverse that behavior so the newest submissions are at the top and oldest at the bottom. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try (put a trigger on onFormSubmit)

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var column = e.values.length + 1;
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, row-1, column);
  range.sort({column: 1, ascending: false});
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike! Can you point me to more information on how to add a trigger?

Comment: Mike, I set up the trigger and get this error on run:TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of undefined

Comment: Do not run onFormSubmit directly from the script editor. This script will automatically fire when a new response is received from your form.

Comment: How do I accept the answer?